# Powershell Test-Connection to an ASA port on a switch can't reconcile without hostname in reference file

Tags: powershell, ping

I am trying to write something simple, using Powershell Test-Connection, to be able to ping a list of IPs from a reference file and output an up or down status. All IPs are for ASA ports not actual servers, so they don't have true hostnames. I can't get the script to work with "nicknames" attached to the IPs in the reference file. Without some sort of name attached to the IP in the output, this tool is no better than looking up individual IPs to ping.

What I have so far:

```
$complist = Get-Content "Path"
foreach($comp in $complist){
    $pingtest = Test-Connection -ComputerName $comp -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if($pingtest){
        Write-Host($comp + " is online")
    }
    else{
        Write-Host($comp + " is not reachable")
    }
}
```

My reference txt file:

```
1.1.1.1 nickname
2.2.2.2 nickname2
```

Even if the port is reachable, the output claims not reachable because DNS cannot reconcile "hostname" with IP.

Comment: You need `Test-NetConnection`, not `Test-Connection`. What port is the target ASA service listening on?

Comment: I have tried Test-NetConnection as with basically the same results. I have to tweak it bit but it's still fails to reconcile the "hostname" and outputs down regardless of reachability. I cannot answer your question though as my organization does not control the actual router configuration, just the physical maintenance of it.

Comment: IP routing can be done two different ways 1) Use IP and Mask to get route 2) Get route from a DNS server using Name.  The Router (not switch) has a control port that you are trying to communicate.  It sound like a mask is wrong someplace in the network.  You have to use PING to try to narrow down the problem.  It could be bad hardware.

Comment: Network uses 1st method. But the network is fully functional, nothing wrong with it or hardware. I'm just trying to build a monitoring tool for my own use so I know when the system plugged into that port goes down without having to log into 3rd party servers. (Also to help newcomers as they await accounts and access)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `String.Split()` method to split the string on whitespace:

```
$complist = Get-Content "Path"

foreach ($line in $complist) {
  # extract ip and nick into separate variables
  $ip,$nickname = $line.Split()

  # ping
  $pingtest = Test-Connection -ComputerName $ip -Quiet

  # output (with nickname) message with status
  if ($pingtest) {
    Write-Host "${nickname} [${ip}] is online"
  }
  else {
    Write-Host "${nickname} [${ip}] is offline"
  }
}
```